# Retrieving photos from my Database and inserting them into my website

Tags: php, mysql

I created a Database with 4 different tables,

**Photos(photoID, type, size, name, dateadded, urlID, caption)
User(userID, fName, lName, password)
Album(albumID, title, datecreated, datemod, size(# of photos))
photoInAlbum(photoID, albumID)**

albumID is a primary key for the albums table, and a foreign key for the photoInAlbums table.

photoID is a primary key for the photos table, and a foreign key for the photoInAlbums table.

photoID and albumID together form the primary key for the photoInAlbums table.

Now I created an album in my database in the Album table, and also created 3 photos in the photo table, with the correct urlID. Now I want to display all the pictures from the one album in your
database by using PHP calls to access the database.
EDIT NEW CODE

```
    <DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/home.css">
    $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database",       3306);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";}
    $albumId =1
    $sql = "SELECT Photos.photoID, Photos.name FROM photos 
    LEFT JOIN photoInAlbum ON (photoInAlbum.photoID = Photos.photoID) 
    WHERE albumID = $albumID";
    $resultset = mysqli_query ....
    while($row = mysqli_result_assoc($resultset)
    {
    /* Here you have the data for a photo in $row */
    /* Use this data to load the photo file from where you've stored it     */
    /* Now display the photo */
}

    </head>

    <body>
        <?php 
    // ** MySQL connection settings ** //

    //Keep this as localhost for the course server
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

    // Your course server username
    define('DB_USER', 'tmh233sp14');    

    // Your course server password
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'ECHOB8Se'); 

    // The name of the database to which you want to connect
    // info230_SP14_username
    define('DB_NAME', 'info230_SP14_tmh233sp14');    
    ?>

         <ul class="navbar">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="albums.php">Albums</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="bestphotos.php">Best Photo's</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="login.php">Member's Area</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    <h1> Photo Album </h1>

        <div id="home"> This is the "Photo Album's" Home Page, where Albums by different users will be showed. 
            </div>
        <p> 
            </p>


    <?php
    $baseURL = "http://info230.cs.cornell.edu/users/tmh233sp14/www/P3";
    $urlID = $result["urlID"]; // this contains "/images/cat.jpg"
    print "<img src='$baseURL.$urlID' />";
    ?>
    <img src='info230.cs.cornell.edu/users/tmh233sp14/www/P3/<?php echo $urlID; ?>' /> 
    <div id="footer">
        <?php include ('footer.php') ?>
    </div>


    </body>
        </html>
```

After this I am not to sure where to go, little lost.

In the end, I am trying to get the pictures to display on my webpage using PHP to access the database
Thanks so much

Comment: What are you even asking? How to perform the query or how to display the images?

Comment: How to display the images on my website using PHP to access the database.

Comment: updated code to include config.php stuff also

Comment: use:
<img src='http://info230.cs.cornell.edu/users/tmh233sp14/www/P3/<?php echo $urlID; ?>' />

Comment: put that under <?php
    $baseURL = "server directory";
    $urlID = $result["urlID"]; // this contains "/images/cat.jpg"
    print "<img src='$baseURL.$urlID' />";
    ?> correct?

Comment: exactly like <?php
    $baseURL = "http://info230.cs.cornell.edu/users/tmh233sp14/www/P3";
    $urlID = $result["urlID"]; // this contains "/images/cat.jpg"
    print "<img src='$baseURL.$urlID' />";
    ?>
    <img src='info230.cs.cornell.edu/users/tmh233sp14/www/P3/<?php echo $urlID; ?>' />

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I'm gonna be brave n take a swing at it. Assuming you already have photos in the database, and now you need to read those photos:

Firstly, [mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) to your database (assuming you're using mysqli)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database", 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";}
```

Now query your database for photos from an album.

```
$albumId = // Whatever album you want to get data for
```

Setup your query to retrieve all photos from a specific album. I'm also assuming your $albumId variable is already protected against [SQL Injection](http://www.cleverlogic.net/articles/sql-injection-depth-attacks-and-prevention-methods).

```
$sql = "SELECT p.photoId, p.name FROM photos p 
LEFT JOIN photoInAlbum pia ON (pia.photoId = p.photoId) 
WHERE albumId = $albumId";
```

Now run the query using [mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) and traverse the resultset, possibly using [mysqli_result_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

```
$resultset = mysqli_query ....
while($row = mysqli_result_assoc($resultset)
{
    /* Here you have the data for a photo in $row */
    /* Use this data to load the photo file from where you've stored it */
    /* Now display the photo */
}
```

So there you go, lots of specifics are not mentioned, you can figure those out by following the reference links.

Comment: Ok thanks man, Im gonna try it tomorrow with a fresh head, been at it for hours. Now this is the first time I am actually implementing mysql for a webpage, does this all go in the config.php file, or in the actual index.php?

Comment: ok thank you, let me post my new code with the information you added above, just to be sure its correct. Ill update OP code now. Thanks!

Comment: would I add this, to where you're comments are?